# Loadmesh succeeding but no mesh found in the callback

Tags: typescript, babylonjs

TL;DR The `addMeshTask` onSuccess gets called, But i got no mesh! haaaaalp!

Hi all, I've been having a problem with my asset-manager when loading meshes.

I've taken a look at the playground 'import mesh' and the code is almost the same, however on the `addMeshTask` success callback I do not get access to the loaded mesh via `task.getLoadedMeshes[0]` (as seen in the playground).

I'm really confused as to what could be causing it to trigger a success event, but not have any 'loaded' meshes.

It is strange, The `addMeshTask` sends two requests, one of which fails, the other passes, could this have something to do with it?

[image]

If you wanna have a poke about with it yourself you can,

My code is open source:

https://github.com/dweng0/wildflower

to get it up and running you'll need to do an `npm install` and `npm install -g`

when thats all done, in the command line, you'll need to run `webpack`

then set up the mock server with `npm run serve`

Then in your browser go to localhost:3000 (have the console open). I've added a debug in the offending function, but it starts in the AssetsManager.ts -> `loadCharacter` function.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Hey! do you mind sharing a repro on playground.babylonjs.com where it is easier to help and comment?

Comment: Hi sorry I thought it was shared